# Is this a 5V to 3.3V level converter?

Tags: transistors, switches

Need to repair a legacy system that has been discontinued and am confused by the PNP based circuit below.

The input signal (max. freq = 20Khz) is applied at IN and is active low. It's TTL level.
It is actually the output of TSOP1738.

The output is tapped from OUT and 3.3V is applied to this point through a weak pullup.
The output signal (OUT) goes to a 3V3 microprocessor

[image: PNP based circuit]

1. Given this information, is the circuit effectively a 3.3V level convertor?
2. Can I replace this with a diode based circuit below for an equally effective 3.3V level convertor?
   (Please disregard that short. It does not exist and was drawn in error)

   [image: diode based circuit]
3. **Why would a company prefer the PNP based circuit over the diode based circuit**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit can be a level converter, yes - essentially from anything above +3.3V to +3.3V + Vebo (the reverse breakdown voltage of the base-emitter junction) which is around 5V minimum according to the [datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/2N/2N3906.pdf), so leaving some leeway, say +7.5V maximum. This circuit has a higher input impedance than the diode circuit, so if you have a weak drive this would be the better choice.

You could replace it with the diode circuit, but remembering due to the diode drop it will only pull down to ~0.7V with silicon (probably lower due to the small current but assume the worst), I'd use a schottky diode to ensure you meet the maximum logic low level of the microcontroller input.

Comment: So 1. the PNP can convert from 7.5V-3.3V to 3.3V? 2. the diode can convert from 7.5V-3.3V to 3.3V with a 0.7V floor? 3. Will not the PNP have a voltage floor for logic 0 like the diode one does (Vce drop)

Comment: 1. Yes 2. The diode circuit can convert from ?-3.3V to 3.3V, the upper voltage depending on it's specs. It has ~0.7V floor. 3. The PNP will have a saturation voltage, yes, but this will only be around 0.2V maximum (probably <0.1V) so it will be lower than the diode circuit.

Comment: So the PNP just serves as a level converter and Toshiba used this design in their equipment as it's a better one the diode based one I came up with.

Answer (score 2):

The upper circuit is called emitter-follower.

It has a much higher input impedance because the current to the load is sunk into the transistor, not Vin.

If you drive the circuit from a high impedance the first circuit is a better choice.