# Connecting Sharp GP2Y1010AU0 (5V) to ESP8266 (3.3V) - pin nr 3 - do I need transistor?

Tags: transistors, resistors, 5v, 3.3v, esp8266

I'm connecting [Sharp GP2Y1010AU0](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/gp2y1010au_e.pdf) to WiFi module ESP8266.

Sharp GP2Y1010AU0 is powered by 5V and ESP8266 by 3.3V.
[image: Schematic]

I wonder **if I need a transistor between Sharp's pin nr 3 and ESP8266**?
If yes, can it be BC846? And how to connect it (through resistor?)?

I am a beginner in electronics. Excuse my bad English.
Defozo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this a 5V to 3.3V level converter?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/is-this-a-5v-to-3-3v-level-converter)

Comment: No, the main question is do I really need to do anything here, since Sharp already has a transistor built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a voltage problem there -- you're feeding the base of a BJT which is a current-mode device, and the pull-up resistor on that line is connected to V-LED, which is also at VCC (3.3V) here. The way they've designed that part, the LED circuit can run on a completely independent power supply.

EDIT: I confused VLED with the base input. You should be fine to run GPIO13 straight to Pin 3, there's no need to source additional current because the LED current is sourced from Pin 1.